# Can show powerpoint and slide it on client chat if using smack Api and openfire in java

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I wonder create application chat using Smack Api and Openfire is server, my problem is if i want show slide show (powerpoint) into chat box, can i do it?
and if i can, is it look like powerpoint - it's mean when user A browse ppt document into chat box , after that user B can see first slide of ppt document, and then user A click forward button and ppt document is slide. User B just see next slide.

Answer (score 1):

If it is one to one, then you can use Smack's [file transfer](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.1.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/filetransfer/package-summary.html) feature to transfer the file to the viewer. Then you can probably use a separate namespace in  to relay the forward/backward command. The side effect is that you can also chat while you are viewing the slide.

To display the PPT file you can [OfficeBean](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/DevelopersGuide/OfficeBean/OfficeBean.xhtml) from you Java application.

You can also use a chatroom for group viewing although you have to figure out what is the best way to transfer the PPT file to people who will be joining the chatroom later. One way would be to implement a service (`disco#item`/`disco#info`) to keep track of meta info like what sessions are currently on and where the files can be located (eg. from Google Docs).

Comment: Thank you Chuk i will try it ! i reply soon :D